# How do I change the input type of the magento custom option based on the value of a combo box?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, magento-1.7

I have two magento product custom options. First one is the combo box of the number of licence that can be purchased for any product , and the second one is text box for the Domain of licence(purchased for which domain).

In combo box i have value like Single licence,2 to 5 licence and 5+licence.

So my requirement is that i want to set text area as the input type of the second custom option instead of the text box when combo box value selected other than single licence.

In text box there is a single domain validation.So now i want to allow users to enter the multiple domains in to that textarea when the combobox value selected other than single licence.

Please draw me on any way if you have any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Custom option has Input Type «Text - Area»

[image]

so, what's the problem to use it?

Comment: ya i know about that custom option ...but i want to change text box and text area dynamically on the change event of the value of the combo box of another custom option....